# window.scrollTo() suddenly stopped working after working fine many years into a legacy project

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is the Firefox webdriver code:

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

which is now not working.

I suspect version upgrade issue,

Here are our versions:
python version is `3.6`
selenium version is `3.141.0`

We have another project using same geckodriver and same firefox on same host and is working fine. Is there a way to print webdriver options, settings etc and compare the two scenarios ?

Comment: If your firefox version has updated you may need to update your geckodriver executable also.
Edit: see the table here https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html

Comment: We can't easily track which upgraded and not even since when it stopped working . We have another project using same geckodriver and same firefox is working fine. Let us know if you have any other debugging ideas.

Comment: some alternatives to try would be using document.body.clientHeight, and/or window.scroll instead of scrollTo...